# Is there a way to remove all default browser capabilities added by chromedriver when initializing the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have made a tests framework to capture and analyze console errors.
For some time now, I saw that the tests are catching console errors that don't happen when launching the usual browser manually. Basically some console errors appear only when the browser is launched by chromedriver.
This is a problem because I have a lot of false negative test results.
I have checked both browser instances with "chrome://version" command and I saw that on the 'Command Line' section, the browser launched by chromedriver has a lot of arguments.

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-background-networking --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="D:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Temp\1\scoped_dir8508_1543433484" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end data:,
```

In the meantime, the chrome browser started manually has only these arguments:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
```

I have spent a bit of time on this, and the only way I see feasible to avoid these errors is only by making chromedriver clear those default arguments,and add new ones. The problem is I don't have a clue how to do that...

Edit 1 -
How my browser configuration section looks and ideas of what I need it to do.

```js
    capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
        loggingPrefs: {
            driver: 'ALL',
            browser: 'ALL'
        },
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ 'a way to remove default args added by chrome driver' ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: your config might be helpful here

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov, I have added a model of how my config looks (not with the chromeOptions text of course). Is this what you asked for?

Comment: so what I wanted to see is what happens if you pass 1. empty array to the `args` prop 2. don't specify anything for `chromeOptions` prop

Comment: If I don't specify anything, the default browser args are added anyway. If add args, they are put in addition to the default ones, so nothing good.